# Nlog not logging the correct logger's name

Tags: c#, .net, nlog

I instantiate the logger in every class I want to log like this

```
private static Logger logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();
```

Then I created a static class with multiple helper functions for logging passing the logger object.

Example of a simple one:

```
    public static void LogMessage(Logger logger, LogLevel logLevel, string message)
    {
        StringBuilder logMessage = new StringBuilder();
        logMessage.AppendLine("Message: " + message);
        logger.Log(logLevel, logMessage);
    }
```

The problem is even if I created the logger in another class, it logs the name of the current class (the static one). I can see the name of the logger in the property list and it has the right name (the name of the class it's been instantiated) when calling the log method. I tried to pass the logger as ref, but it does the same thing.

Does anyone knows why this happens?

Comment: Not an answer, but it sounds like you could very easily turn this into an [extension method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/bb383977.aspx) so you could just do `logger.LogMessage(INFO, "msg");` rather than `Whatever.LogMessage(logger, ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is expected behavior. There are some solutions:

- Just create a static logger every class, which is [recommend](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Tutorial#creating-loggers), or
- Use `LogManager.GetLogger("loggername")` and pass your name, or
- Use the fluent logging which is included in NLog, see [news post](http://nlog-project.org/2015/01/20/have-you-seen-our-new-fluent-interface.html), or
- Use the static class in [Fody Anotar](https://github.com/Fody/Anotar): `LogTo.Debug("TheMessage");`